# Format cell value to number having comma

Tags: c#, excel, webforms, openxml

My scenario is am trying to figure out how to add formatting to numbers in a cell. I want my number to have a comma for eg: `50,000`, 4 digits number like `2000` should stay the same though. I am using  the `OpenXml` SDK.

```
 var cell = new Cell();
 cell.DataType = CellValues.Number;
 cell.CellValue = new CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
cell.CellValue = new CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString("#,###"));
```

And if you want to just separate numbers that have more than 4 digits, you have to use conditional Command like "if" or etc . like this:

```
cell.CellValue = new CellValue(dsrow[col].Lenght>4
 ? dsrow[col].ToString("#,###")
 :dsrow[col].ToString());
```

Comment: BUT the problem now is that even if the cellValues=Number is specified ,a string is being saved in the excel file

Comment: Do you want to always save as a number? @keshav

Comment: Yes,this is my user requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can try String.Format("{#,###}", 1234);
The related key word is **string format number thousands separator**

Comment: This works for me:   string test = String.Format("{0:n0}", intvalue);

BUT the problem now is that even if the cellValues=Number is specified ,a string is being saved in the excel file